# How can I get the last 10 records

Tags: postgresql

I have a db with +- 60000 records in, I need to obtain the last 10 records entered, can this be done via postgres? I was thinking off maybe setting the offset to 50 990 and the limit to 10 or something similar, but not sure if this will be efficient?

Comment: Do you have a timestamp or serial field?

Comment: @MrEdmundo , by a unix timestamp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like the following perhaps:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
ORDER BY your_timestamp DESC
LIMIT 10
```

If you want the result sorted by the timestamp, you can wrap this in another query and sort again. You might want to take a look at the execution plan but this shouldn't be too inefficient.

Answer (score 4):

```
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

If `id` is indexed, this will be very efficient. Could naturally also be a timestamp.